# paper_trail and keeping relations untouched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, relationship, paper-trail-gem

Is there any possibility to force paper_trail to not change relations when it's version changes?

My app is a betting software and I need to keep user bets on the one that was active at the time when he was betting, retaining the possibility to change odds.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to ignore updates to certain attributes? So like if odds are changed then don't do anything?

Or do you mean for it not to create a version when a related object changes?

Either way I think the following from the docs will work

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#choosing-attributes-to-monitor

```
has_paper_trail :skip => [:attribute_or_relationship]
```

Which will stop the version from being created but also leave out the above from all versions.

Comment: I rather want it the other way. The odd has many bets, but when odd is changed then all already created bets are untouched.

Comment: What do the odds and bets models look like, many what are the belongs_to and has_many statements?